# WIX heat, ProjectReference.ContentProject what does it mean

Tags: wix

I have a new .Net application where I have made a WIX installer for. The WIX installer is a copy paste from other solutions where it is working without problems. It makes use of heat to automatically harvest the files needed. However, now I have run into a problem where it doesn't work for the current project. In the proj file where the heatdirectory is described, there is the following condition

```
Condition="'%(ProjectReference.ContentProject)'=='True'"
```

This condition works in the other solutions, however now it means that heat is not run when build.
I have googled, but I haven't been able to find out what `ProjectReference.ContentProject` means ?
Can anybody enlighten me, what it means and why it might not work in this solution ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContentProject` only means something if you include it in your `ProjectReference`. See [an example here](https://code-examples.net/en/q/819429).

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\MyWCF.WcfService\MyWCF.WcfService.csproj">
    <Name>MyWCF.WcfService</Name>
    <Project>{8e528b38-2826-4793-a66d-f6ff181e1139}</Project>
    <Private>True</Private>
    <RefProjectOutputGroups>Binaries;Content;Satellites</RefProjectOutputGroups>
    <RefTargetDir>INSTALLFOLDER</RefTargetDir>
    <ContentProject>True</ContentProject>
    <DoNotHarvest>True</DoNotHarvest>
    <PackageThisProject>True</PackageThisProject>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Great thank you, I did a lot of searching but couldn't find the info.